How to manage different required fields for two type users role in a single userModel.ts file in using nextjs and mongo user registartion API
Here is my code is it correct? Or give me best suggestion. I have two type user role like candidate and business and both have multiple different fields and I want to manage all the fields in one userModel.ts file.
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['candidate', 'business'],
    required: true,
  },
  // ... Other common fields applicable to both roles
  // Define optional fields specific to each role (if any)
  candidateSpecific?: {
    // Candidate-specific fields (optional)
  },
  businessSpecific?: {
    // Business-specific fields (optional)
  },
});

export default mongoose.models.users || mongoose.model('users', userSchema);


Yes, but there are a few improvements you can make to handle the specific fields for each role more effectively. You can use Mongoose's mixed type for the fields specific to each role and ensure that they are only required or present depending on the user's role.
and do not forgot to user pre method to specify role.


import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  role: 'candidate' | 'business';
  candidateSpecific?: {
    // Define candidate-specific fields here
    resume?: string;
    portfolio?: string;
  };
  businessSpecific?: {
    // Define business-specific fields here
    companyName?: string;
    companyWebsite?: string;
  };
}

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['candidate', 'business'],
    required: true,
  },
  candidateSpecific: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: {},
  },
  businessSpecific: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: {},
  },
});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this as IUser;

  if (user.role === 'candidate') {
    user.businessSpecific = undefined;
  } else if (user.role === 'business') {
    user.candidateSpecific = undefined;
  }

  next();
});

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);



And like this you can use that


 const newUser = new User({
    email: 'candidate@example.com',
    password: 'securepassword',
    role: 'candidate',
    candidateSpecific: {
      resume: 'link_to_resume',
      portfolio: 'link_to_portfolio',
    },
  });
  
  
   const newUser = new User({
    email: 'business@example.com',
    password: 'securepassword',
    role: 'business',
    businessSpecific: {
      companyName: 'Company Inc.',
      companyWebsite: 'https://company.com',
    },
  });




Your data objects suggest that candidate and business specific fields should be handled with separate models.
However, since you want to handle all data in one model you can use Subdocuments and pass a function to the required validator to ensure that candidateSpecific fields are included if role is candidate or businessSpecific fields if role is business.
An example would be:
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// Create a schema for candidate. This will not add a new collection or model
const candidateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    whatBroughtYouToPikle: {
        type: String,
    },
    currentStatus: {
        type: String,
    },
    //...
});

// Create a schema for business. This will not add a new collection or model
const businessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: {
        type: String,
    },
    companySize: {
        type: String,
    },
    //...
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['candidate', 'business'],
        required: true,
    },
    // ... 
    candidateSpecific:{
        type: candidateSchema,
        required: function (){
            return this.role === "candidate";
        }
    },
    businessSpecific: {
        type: businessSchema,
        required: function (){
            return this.role === "business";
        }
    },
});

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);

